# Как организовать роутинг для URL?

Tags: php, ооп, маршрутизация, mod-rewrite, route

Здравствуйте!

Сейчас у меня система роутинга работает так:

Есть url такого вида: site.ru/market/category/velosipedi/page/25

Соответственно разбиваю строку на массив, в котором первый элемент это контроллер, а все последующие это параметр и его значение.

Но на многих сайтах есть URL такого типа: site.ru/velosipedi/gornie-velosipedi

Как парсить такие URL?

Как я понимаю, мне нужна будет отдельная таблица в базе данных, для того чтобы сравнивать значения.

```
route_id | name             | controller
1        |velosipedi        | market_controller
2        |gornie-velosipedi | market_controller
3        |contacts          | contacts_controller
```

Правильно ли я понял?

Но все равно остается непонятный вопрос, как автоматизировать такие URL:

1. site.ru/velosipedi/gornie-velosipedi
2. site.ru/velosipedi/gornie-velosipedi/page/25
3. site.ru/categorija-bloga/name-post

Ведь вложенность категорий может быть разная.

Comment: Вы не хотите использовать фреймворк?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь не нужно писать роутинг для всех параметров запроса. Достаточно только для первого.
Для этого - да, может понадобиться отдельная таблица алиасов, вида

```
name             | controller
velosipedi       | market_controller
```

при этом последующие параметры хранить в ней не нужно - определив контроллер, мы просто передаем все полученные параметры в него, и он сам уже внутри себя разбирается с ними.
Также не нужно хранить в этой таблице явные вызовы контроллеров - их список в любом случае всегда есть в системе и проверять нужно по нему.

То есть, берем первый параметр и прогоняем по такому несложному алгоритму:

1. Проверяем по списку контроллеров. Если нашли - вызываем контроллер.
2. Проверяем по таблице алиасов. Нашли - вызываем найденный контроллер.
3. 404

Вместо таблицы можно использовать некий API - скажем, опрашивать контроллеры на предмет их алиасов. Так даже будет, наверное, правильнее. Чтобы за velosipedi отвечало не ядро, а market_controller.

От себя добавлю, что гнаться за очень уж человекопонятным URL не стоит. Будет ли слово market в адресе, или не будет - этого 95% пользователей даже не заметят.
Так убирание его из адреса - довольно бессмысленная трата времени.

Comment: Спасибо! Опять Вы меня выручили!!!

Answer (score 1):

Необходимы правила роутинга, а не точные варианты.
Т.е. вплоть до проверки адреса на регулярное выражение.
Expample: `site.com/page/15`.
Где-то в правилах роутера можно сделать что-то типа: `URI: 'page\/?(\d*)', Controller: 'Page', Method: 'View'`, в метод передать выдранное число, т.е. номер страницы (если есть).

Вложенность категорий должен обрабатывать контроллер, а не роутер.
Он запустит нужный класс, главный, а он уже разберётся и запустит другие, если надо.